# Tool/library to make a stacked bar chart in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I was thinking of using flexmonster, but it's not free. So, I'm thinking of using [angular-d3-charts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-d3-charts). Is there any better alternative?
Or some good reporting tools (free) that can be integrated within an Angular 8 application.

Comment: I am using native JS libraries - no need for ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion google charts api is a very good one.
There's also an angular wrapper: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-google-charts